# getFromLocationName() returns null on android tablet

Tags: android, tablet

```
cmap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {   System.out.println("Cmap initial:=lat:-"+lat+" lang:-"+lon);
            Toast t=Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Location"+lat+"lang:-"+lon,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
            tlname=elname.getText().toString();
            tladdr=eladdr.getText().toString();
            addressInput=tlname+" "+tladdr;
            System.out.println("address:-"+addressInput);
            Toast t3=Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Address"+addressInput,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t3.show();
            try
            {
                Geocoder gc1 = new Geocoder(
                        getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());

                foundAdresses = gc1.getFromLocationName(addressInput, 5);
                showAdressResults.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                Toast t1=Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Location...."+foundAdresses,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t1.show();
                System.out.println("faddress:-"+foundAdresses);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (foundAdresses.size() == 0)
            { // if no address found,
                // display an error
                Dialog locationError = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        Gotask.this).setIcon(0).setTitle(
                        "Error").setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                        .setMessage(
                        "Sorry, your address doesn't exist.")
                        .create();
                locationError.show();

            } else 
            { // else display address on map
                for (int i = 0; i < foundAdresses.size(); ++i)
                {

                    Address x = foundAdresses.get(i);
                    lat =  (x.getLatitude() *100);
                    lon = (float) x.getLongitude();
                    System.out.println("Cmap:=lat:-"+lat+" lang:-"+lon);


                }
                navigateToLocation((lat * 1000000), (lon * 1000000),myMap);
            }


        }

    });
```

Comment: try
{ Geocoder gc1 = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
foundAdresses = gc1.getFromLocationName(addressInput, 5);
showAdressResults.sendEmptyMessage(0);
} catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();
}if (foundAdresses.size() == 0){err0r msg}
else { for (int i = 0; i < foundAdresses.size(); ++i)
{Address x = foundAdresses.get(i);
lat =  (x.getLatitude() *100);
lon = (float) x.getLongitude();
}navigateToLocation((lat * 1000000), (lon * 1000000),myMap);

Comment: paste you code by clicking edit option below ur question

Comment: append your problem statement also

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this kind of issue in reverse Geo coding so i am use Google api for it.
Refer [this link for](http://girishbhutiya.blogspot.in/2010/04/reverse-geocoding-in-android-2-2-froyo-api-level-greater-than-8.html) google api to use in reverse geocoding.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when i was developing an app based on google maps.The problem was with the devcie ,the one which i am  using did't support backend service(a kind of service comes with device) which is responsible for working of GeoCoding related APIs.So i decided to use services exposed by google to query for lat & longitude for the required Address.So just give a try.

Refer this link to know more

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Please refer following links:

[How can you tell when an Android device has a Geocoder backend service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255020/how-can-you-tell-when-an-android-device-has-a-geocoder-backend-service)

[Android; Geocoder, why do I get "the service is not available"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619924/android-geocoder-why-do-i-get-the-service-is-not-available)

Here is a sample request for geocoding request to obtain Latitude and longitude from response after parsing Xml output.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false

There is a clear cut example in the link mentioned earlier.